# Hortonwork is not getting connected with browser after being installed in vmware

Tags: hadoop, hive, vmware, hortonworks-data-platform

I have successfully installed hortonworks sandbox in vmware and finally I am getting this screenshot of vmware

[image]

However I tried that `ipaddress` in browser but getting below error .

> This site can’t be reached
>   192.168.247.135 took too long to respond.
>   Try:
>   Reloading the page
>   Checking the connection
>   Checking the proxy and the firewall
>   ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: i tried that url in the main os browser .

Comment: Have you tried to ping the ip adress?

Comment: yes its showing request timed out .

Comment: Is your VM connected to the network? Is a network adapter configured in the VM configuration?

Comment: Yes i configure VM as NAT and sharing the host IP address .

Comment: is there any modification need to be done ?

Comment: Change your adopter setting to Bridge adopter, save it and try

Comment: After changing to bridge adopter ping is coming but still not able to connect in browser .

Comment: Is there any change need to be done in browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the Hortornworks Sandbox from putty or browser you have to perform 2 steps in Network setting as below in picture:

- Set Adapter 1 attached to NAT

[image]

- Set Adapter 2 attached to Host-only Adapter

[image]

Please refer the steps from the pictures above and it will work because same setting is working for me.

Comment: One more thing , which console should i use in windows os to connect sandbox .

Comment: Use putty or mobaxterm to connect

Comment: Hello Sir - I followed your step, this still doesn't work for me. I added both the network adapters. But still i get "Connectivity Issues detected!" while starting the VM in my laptop